# How to see contract execution time in Remix IDE?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, remix

I want to see the total time in msec for each step of the smart contract while deploying in REMIX ide (online). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: >  I want to see the total time in msec for each step of the smart contract 

Why? Your question does not make any sense. Transaction times vary greatly and they are not mostly dependent on your code or Remix IDE.

Comment: Yes, I want to measure the efficiency of my code against another approach.

Comment: That is not how smart contracts work, so you are asking https://xyproblem.info/ question. Your question should contain 1) what are you doing 2) why 3) why do you think you need to have performance efficiency 4) what is a good measurement 5) how to perform it. I suggest you edit your question and add more context information.